# makefile & gcc -c compilation - how to name object files

Tags: gcc, makefile

I'm playing with makefile for class project.

(1) I need to create debug rule. But I don't know how to give specific names to object files that I need (do I need?) to create that debug-enabled executable.

(2)I assume file can be further reduced to fewer lines of code. Could you suggest how?

This is my makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -std=c11
OBJ = hospital.o parse.o structure.o description.o patientList.o diseaseList.o
DOBJ = hospital.dbg.o parse.dbg.o structure.dbg.o description.dbg.o patientList.dbg.o diseaseList.dbg.o

all: hospital

hospital: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

hospital.o: hospital.c structure.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^

parse.o: parse.c parse.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^

structure.o: structure.c structure.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ 

patientList.o: patientList.c patientList.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^

diseaseList.o: diseaseList.c diseaseList.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^

description.o: description.c description.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^

debug: $(DOBJ)
    $(CC) $^ -o hospital.dbg

hospital.dbg.o: hospital.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -g $@ $< -c

parse.dbg.o: parse.c parse.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -g $@ $< -c

structure.dbg.o: structure.c structure.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -g $@ $< -c

patientList.dbg.o: patientList.c patientList.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -g $@ $< -c

diseaseList.dbg.o: diseaseList.c diseaseList.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -g $@ $< -c

description.dbg.o: description.c description.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -g $@ $< -c

clean:
    rm *.o hospital.dbg hospital *~

.PHONY: all clean
```

Thanks

Comment: `DOBJ = ${OBJ:.o=.dbg.o}` ensures that the `OBJ` and `DOBJ` macros are kept in synchrony.

Comment: I compile with the `-g -O3` most of the time.  That's mostly debuggable, but also optimized.  When I don't want the optimization screwing me up in the debugger, I drop the `-O3` (rather than add the `-g`).  And I simply do an unconditional build (`make -B` with GNU `make`) to change the flags.  I build `CFLAGS` from lots of bits: `CFLAGS = ${WFLAGS} ${OFLAGS} ${GFLAGS} ${DFLAGS} ${IFLAGS} ${UFLAGS}` (for warning options, optimization, debug, defines (`-DDEBUG`), includes (`-I${HOME}/inc`) and command line over-rides (UFLAGS).  And I can use `make -B OFLAGS=` to build without optimization.

Comment: Have you looked at [pattern rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules)?

Comment: Ok. The thing is I need to make rule to produce *.dbg.o. For example gcc -g -c file.c needs to produce file.gdb.o